# How to prove the equality of power series below?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, theta-functions

Assume
$$
F\left( x \right) := \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}{x^{\left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right) ^2}}, G\left( x \right) := \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}{x^{n^2}}, H\left( x \right) := \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^nx^{n^2}},
$$
I have to prove
$$
\left( G\left( x \right) \right) ^2+\left( H\left( x \right) \right) ^2=2\left( G\left( x^2 \right) \right) ^2
$$
and
$$
\left( G\left( x \right) \right) ^4=\left( F\left( x \right) \right) ^4+\left( H\left( x \right) \right) ^4.
$$
After using Mathematica I find that it may have relation with [EllipticTheta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticTheta.html). But it seems to be so difficult to me. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: @jjagmath, the only thing I can do is to expand $(G(x))^2$ to a form with two-letter-sum, which ends with nothing at all, and it doesn't seem to be a general method when dealing with the second equaltion. So I think we do not need to waste time on my thought.

Comment: Is it $H(x)$ rather than $F(x)$ you're defining in your third formula?

Comment: Yes, thanks for reminding me.@RobertIsrael

Comment: Your $F(x),G(x),H(x)$ are the [Theta functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.2) $\theta_2(0,x),\theta_3(0,x),\theta_4(0,x)$. The 4th degree identity is [known](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.7.E5).

Comment: This is pretty standard in theory of theta functions. An elementary proof is available in my blog post: https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions.html?m=0

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient of $x^k$ in $G(x)^2$ is the number of ways to write $k = m^2 + n^2$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers.
The coefficient of $x^k$ in $H(x)^2$ is the number of ways to write $k = m^2 + n^2$ where $m +n$ is even minus the number of ways where $m+n$ is odd, thus $(-1)^k$ times the coefficient in $G(x)^2$.
So the coefficient of $x^k$ in $G(x)^2 + H(x)^2$ is twice the number of ways to write $k = m^2 + n^2$ when $k$ is even, $0$ when $k$ is odd.

The coefficient of $x^k$ in $G(x^2)^2$ is $0$ if $k$ is odd (since $G(x^2)^2$ is an even function), and the coefficient of $x^{k/2}$ in $G(x)^2$ if $k$ is even. So that gives you your first equation.